# WPF trigger/bindings not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatrigger

I'm trying to setup a TextBox subclass that will change its style based on a few different things, and I'm running into two problems.  The first Trigger, the VisualBrush one, triggers properly but won't write the text in the String myName.  I tried making myName a property but for some reason the set method throws a StackOverFlowException.

The second problem is with the DataTrigger, which isn't getting triggered even though isRequired is set to false.

This is all within a custom control that inherits TextBox.

Here's my XAML:

```
    <TextBox.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Gray" FontSize="24">
                                        <TextBlock.Text>
                                            <Binding Path="myName" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
                                        </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                        </VisualBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=isRequired, Source={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="100" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBox.Style>
```

CS:

```
    public partial class SuperTB : TextBox
{
    public String myName
    {
        get { return myName; }
        set {}
    }

    DependencyProperty isRequiredProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("isRequired", typeof(Boolean), typeof(SuperTB));

    public Boolean isRequired
    {
        get { return (Boolean)GetValue(isRequiredProperty); }
        set { SetValue(isRequiredProperty, value); }
    }

    public SuperTB()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myName = "Unicorns!";
    }

}
```

This is the code that StackOverflows it.  Also failing to work but no Exception is:

```
public string myName = "Rainbows!";
```

Comment: Please only use the Visual Studio tag if your question actually has anything to do with it. (The fact that you wrote your code in it does on its own **not** entail that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 public string myName    
 {        
     get { return myName; }        
     set {}    
 }
```

that property getter is returning **itself**, hence the stack overflow.

and the setter is doing nothing, hence the "failing to work"

you *probably* want:

```
 private string myName; // lower case!
 public string MyName    // upper case!
 {        
     get { return myName; }        
     set { myName = value; }    
 }
```

or even

```
 public string myName { get; set; }
```

and even then this still won't work like you expect, since nothing is firing any property change notifications there, so nobody will notice that myName ever changes.

Comment: I now understand the stackoverflow.  I changed it as such, and implemented INotifyPropertyChanged and fire it in the setter for myName but the binding still isn't doing anything.  [Here's my new code.](http://pastebin.com/w5P3mDjA)

Comment: do you have binding errors/warnings going out to the output window?  I'd check there first.  I don't see anything obvious right now...

Comment: The relevant output, which I can't make sense of, is: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'myName' property not found on 'object' ''RelativeSource' (HashCode=4960368)'. BindingExpression:Path=myName; DataItem='RelativeSource' (HashCode=4960368); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Comment: are you setting this style on an instance of YOUR custom textbox class (SuperTB) or to a plain Textbox?  otherwise, something is wrong with how you've specified your relativesource binding there?

Comment: The style is inlined in the xaml definition of SuperTB.  My binding is `<Binding Path="myName" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />` which looks correct to me?

Comment: Your binding is on a TextBlock within the xaml.  Self really means self-- if the binding lives on a TextBlock, it'll try to bind to the textblock.  NOT your control.  Make your source a RelativeSource with FindAncestor and look for the SuperTB type.

Comment: Also note that your implementation of OnNotifyPropertyChanged doesn't follow the idiomatic practice of assigning the event to a local temporary prior to testing for null and raising.  In a multi-threaded or re-entrant scenario (that you aren't even aware of), your code can explode.  Instead, OnNotifyPropertyChanged should be something like this:
`var event = this.PropertyChanged;
if (event != null) event(this, args);`

This eliminates a race condition that exists between testing for null and executing the delegates on the event.